# Index on json list

Tags: postgresql, index, json

I have an attribute (ids) defined as jsonb in Postgres that contains a list of values:

```
CREATE TABLE test.id_data2 (
    key bigint NOT NULL,
    ids jsonb, 
    CONSTRAINT tag_data2_pk PRIMARY KEY (key)
);
```

- ids contains a list of ids that are numeric strings:  '["2", "4", "6", "8", "10"]
- some records may have 50+ ids and I may have 20mm records
- this is being used as a cross-reference to find which keys contain a specific value
  Once the data is stored, I need to find all records that have a specific id:

```
from test.id_data2 
where ids::jsonb ? '8'
```

This works but results in a full table scan.  Is there a way to create an index on the ids column such that it won't do a full table scan?

Comment: A GIN index would be usable: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html. But a properly normalized table with a declared foreign key might be a better choice to begin with

Comment: How would I declare the gin index?  I tried this: create index i2_tag_data on test.id_data2 using GIN((ids::jsonb)) It returns success, but I need it to index each specific value in the list. Regarding the normalized table, I was trying to avoid a table with 1billion+ potential rows

Comment: Yes, that is the way to index a `jsonb` column (the cast is completely useless as the column is already defined as `jsonb`). You don't "index specific values" with a database index. You index the values of a column for all rows.

Comment: Your approach is no good. Don't use JSON for that. A large normalized table is much better in every respect.